# Return value from sort function

Tags: javascript

I am sorting through an array so that the array will be sorted from smallest to greatest.

currently I do.

```
let arr = arr2.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a < b) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

But I was told to do

```
let arr = arr2.sort((a, b) => (
    a - b
));
```

Both of these work fine, but I am trying to figure out how returning `a - b` is equivalent to my first approach.

Comment: it is not the same approach, but it respects greater values as well (return value greater than zero).

Comment: I would be surprised if second approach worked unless you return `a.timestamp - b.timestamp`

Comment: The first approach is actually wrong. Returning `0` would mean that the two items are equal, which isn't necessarily the case. Since comparing `a, b`, and `b, a` in different order doesn't produce consistent results, you can get the WRONG result from the sorting algorithm.

Comment: @vlaz How can I write a sort function so that it would always return consistent results? Would I just have to check for both cases (a - b and b - a)?

Comment: "*Both of these work fine*" - no they don't, that's why you are told to use the second one. They are not equivalent, the first one doesn't work.

Comment: @HenryLee just `a - b` is enough. When I say "consistent" I mean that if `compare(a, b)` deems `a` as the smaller, then `compare(b, a)` should say the same even if it's actually that `b` is bigger - same idea. In your case one time `a` could be smaller than `b` in another they could be equal. It all depends in which order you compare them. That's inconsistent.

Comment: @vlaz We got a canonical question that explains comparison consistency :-)

Comment: @Bergi as a matter of fact I do :P https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison

Comment: @vlaz How can I ensure that they are always compared in a certain order?

Comment: @HenryLee you don't, that's the point. Assuming you have the array `[1, 2, 3]` the sorting algorithm could call `compare(1, 2)` but it could also call `compare(2, 1)`, depending on the implementation. If one of these tells it that `1` is smaller, the other one that `2 == 1`, it cannot sort the elements. That's why returning `a - b` is consistent - `compare(1, 2)` gives you `-1` or "1 is smaller" whereas `compare(2, 1)` returns `1` or "2 is bigger". The logical conclusion is the same in either case `1 < 2`.

Comment: @vlaz I see. I am still not clear from the answer why return `a-b` works, is it because it can either be less than 0 (any negative number) or greater than 0. So if `a = 5` and `b = 10`, and `a - b` returns `-5` this evaluats to false since it is a negative number while `b - a` returns a positive and evaluates to true?

Comment: No, it doesn't evaluate to `false`. A negative value means `a` is smaller than `b`. A positive value means that `a` is bigger. Read the dupe - it explains why there is a three-way comparison.

Answer (score 3):

You still need to compare the same property. And whil the sort works on the same object, you do not need an assignment to a new variable. Both shares then the same object reference.

```
arr2.sort((a, b) => a.timestamp - b.timestamp);
```

Just an addition, if you just return `-1` or `0`, you fool the sorting algorithm bcause you omit `1`. That leads to more sorting cycles than maybe necessary or is simply wrong!

```js
// unpredictable                                                  EDGE CHROME/FF
console.log([4, 3, 2, 1].sort((a, b) => +(a > b)).join(' ')); //  desc    asc
console.log([4, 3, 2, 1].sort((a, b) => +(a < b)).join(' ')); //  desc   desc
console.log([4, 3, 2, 1].sort((a, b) => -(a > b)).join(' ')); //  desc   desc
console.log([4, 3, 2, 1].sort((a, b) => -(a < b)).join(' ')); //  asc    desc

// predictable right!
console.log([4, 3, 2, 1].sort((a, b) => a - b).join(' '));    //  asc     asc
console.log([4, 3, 2, 1].sort((a, b) => b - a).join(' '));    //  desc   desc
```

Comment: `That leads to more sorting cycles than maybe necessary or is simply wrong!` more likely just wrong. But again, who knows. If comparing two object in different order does not produce similar (flipped) results, then the sorting order is undefined. It's possible that the sorting does try to compare *every* single pair of elements but that's not guaranteed - some comparisons can be skipped, if they are assumed to be unneeded. E.g., `a` is less than `b` and `b` is equal to `c`, therefore no comparison is needed between `a` and `c`.

Comment: So does the return of just `a - b` work because whenever it is returned as <= -1, it treats it as less than 0 or false?

Comment: sort required a numerical value, not a boolean (this would be converted to number). the delta of the numbers is just a value which represents the relation of both values.